# Angular 2 get value of <option> on change

Tags: select, angular

I have an array for my select:

```
private ranges = [
  { text: "Last 30 days", value: 30 },
  { text: "Last 60 days", value: 60 },
  { text: "Last 90 days", value: 90 },
  { text: "Last 365 days", value: 365 },
  { text: "All", value: '' }
];
```

and select:

```
<select id="ActivityRange" #sel (change)='select(sel.value)'>
  <option *ngFor="#range of ranges" [value]="range.value">
   {{range.text}}
  </option>
</select>
```

and trying to get the value of select on change ("30" for "Last 30 days"), but i'm getting text value ("Last 30 days" instead of "30")

```
 select(selectedValue) {
   console.log(selectedValue);
 }
```

Here is the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PMkIxq0JbL3IimBjPVp4?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have should work, i.e.:

```
<option *ngFor="#range of ranges" [value]="range.value">
```

```
select(selectedValue) {
   console.log(selectedValue);
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lYMwBbqqxSBdV9RQyiEg?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I think that's a different issue.  That one is about event binding.  This one is about property binding.

Comment: This still console.logs the text value. Please see the plunk

Comment: Sure but it's likely when event binding doesn't work that  it also doesn't work in property binding. Therefore my question if you checked if this works :)

Comment: I did, but as you and @mishap pointed out, I accidentally left my console.log() change in the plunk, so that's the real answer... I'll update, thanks.

Comment: I'm really trying to set the value property of each <option> to a value property of each item in array and get that on change. It's not a conversion issue im talking about here.

Comment: @mishap, see my updated answer and plunker.  Tested in Chrome and FF. But it is no different from your original code.  So I may end up deleting this answer.

Comment: @mishap, consider deleting your question, since I didn't really provide any additional information.  (Had I not been confused about getting an integer result at first, I would have just commented on your question.)

Answer (score 1):

I had to use [attr.value] to make it work with latest Angular 2 version:

```
 <option *ngFor="#range of ranges" [attr.value]="range.value">
```

Comment: Just FYI, `[value]="range.value"` works fine with beta.15.  I updated the Plunker in my answer to use beta.15, and it still works.  And, the Angular docs use `[value]="..."` in the [Forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html#!#add-powers-with-ngfor-) dev guide.  So this is probably the recommended way to bind values to option elements.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Yes, I noticed that too today. You answer is the accepted one

Comment: This solved my problem. Do you have any explanation why `[value]="range.value"` doesn't yield the desired result i.e binding to `text` instead of `value`